# Update rows with variable's value and use default if variable is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a variable:

```
declare @x int = /* smth here */
```

And I have a table with column (e.g. `ColX`) which is `not null` and have a `default` constraint. Now I want to update some rows in the table in a way like this:

```
update MyTable
set ColX = isnull(@x, default)
where blah-blah-blah
```

Obviously it can't be executed since sql-server will show you an error, but I think this example clearly reflect what I want to do.
So the question is how it can be done?
Thanks!

**UPDATE**
So I have now these ways:

- do it through system views - get column_default propery and use dynamic query execution
- perform both cases in separate subqueries:

  ```
  if @x is null then update /* use default */ else update /* use @x */
  ```

  This way is a straightforward and the simpliest. Maybe even the most transparent for the other guy who'll read it further. Also keep in mind it will require also to have separate inserts for both

  ```
  @x is null /* use default */
  ```

  and

  ```
  @x is not null /* use @x */
  ```

  cases
- create user-defined function:

  ```
  create function GetValueForColX(@value int) returns int
  as begin
      return isnull(@value, /* default value */)
  end
  ```

  And then use it in default - `(GetValueForColX(null))` and in insert/update query `GetValueForColX(@x)`

Comment: @danihp, ah, I just hoped that there's a shorter way to do it :) Thanks. If no more simple'll be in near future I'll close the question

Comment: @danihp, Ok. Let's say I have default = 0. There's a `((0))` in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_DEFAULT for this column. Which way is the best to retrieve default value from it?

Comment: Don't close the question, is a good question. I'm also waiting to know people answers (I have deleted my first comment to increase interest for your question ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default shown in system tables applies to CLR procs only.

If you don't want 2 separate updates, use a scalar UDF in both the DEFAULT and in the update.
So instead of, say, GETDATE(), wrap this in CREATE FUNCTION, change the default and update to use this.

But two updates is simpler...

Comment: Nice idea. I've just tried it and yes, it works. But I can't disagree that two updates is maybe clearer and simpler way.

Comment: But it means that I need to also do 2 inserts in this case (one for non-null value and one for default). So I'm not sure now :)

Comment: @pkuderov: Either way is good. Both work. My idea could be slightly harder to maintain (say you change GETDATE() to GETUTCDATE(), unlikely though) vs duplicating calls which could be easy to typo if you need to change it. Personally, I'd use my way for the typo potential: defaults rarely change

Answer (score 3):

Possible workaround using two updates

```
DECLARE @x int
IF @x IS NULL
  update MyTable
  set ColX = DEFAULT
ELSE 
  update MyTable
  set ColX = @x
```